# Typescript - Using a value from then in function return block

Tags: javascript, typescript, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have this function:

```
function configureClient(): ApolloClient<ApolloCache<any>> {
    let myToken = getOktaToken().then(token => {
        return token
    });

    return new ApolloClient<InMemoryCache>({
        uri: "someUrl",
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        headers: {
            someAuth: myToken
        }
    });
}
```

I'm want `someAuth: myToken` in `headers` of the return block to be set however not sure how do this using this `then` block.

Also to add:

Generally, I would have done, `let myToken = await getOktaToken()` - however I'm unable to make the `async function configureClient()` as that `ApolloClient<ApolloCache<any>>` complains about some ES3. I presume this would have worked?
`Type 'typeof DefaultClient' in not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise compatible constructor value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous -- the callback you pass to `then` is evaluated after your function returns. You can make the whole `configureClient` function return a Promise, but that will mean you will have to change how you're using it elsewhere in your app (again, because at that point, the whole client will be initialized asynchronously).

```
function configureClient(): Promise<ApolloClient<ApolloCache<any>>> {
  return getOktaToken().then(token => {
    return new ApolloClient<InMemoryCache>({
      uri: "someUrl",
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      headers: {
        someAuth: token
      }
    });
  });
}

// or the equivalent using async/await syntax

async function configureClient(): Promise<ApolloClient<ApolloCache<any>>> {
  const token = await getOktaToken()
  return new ApolloClient<InMemoryCache>({
    uri: "someUrl",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    headers: {
      someAuth: token
    }
  });
}
```

You could delay rendering your app until the client is fetched. For example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    configureClient().then(setClient)
  }, [])

  if (!client) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      ...
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

If you have headers that need to be fetched asynchronously, though, the preferred way to do so is using `apollo-link-context`. You should [stop using Apollo Boost](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/boost-migration/) or better yet [migrate to the latest Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/migrating/apollo-client-3-migration/). Then you can configure the links for your client instance and add a Context Link as shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/api/link/apollo-link-context/).

Comment: Oh, that new Apollo Client looks interesting, and it looks like it has `@apollo/react-hooks` - I'll give that a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I ended up continue to use Apollo Boost for the time being and added the header using this: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3044#issuecomment-528188436